# One reader / one writer no-memory-allocation lock-free ring-buffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, circular-list

I have two threads - one thread queues items another thread dequeues. `dequeue` is fast enough and so we can assume that queue is never contains more than 65536 items.

C++ doesn't contain "ring-buffer."  Boost has one, but it doesn't allow "reuse" of elements. So I wrote my own ring-buffer, which I think is very fast and requires no memory allocation.  The code below has not been tested but it should show the general idea.

Do you find my code fine? Can you suggest how I can improve it or if there's something I can use instead of it?
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

template<class T> class ArrayPool
{
public:
    ArrayPool() {
    };

    ~ArrayPool(void) {
    };

    // reader thread
    bool IsEmpty() {
        return curReadNum == curWriteNum;
    }

    // reader thread
    T* TryGet()
    {
        if (curReadNum == curWriteNum)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        T* result = &storage[curReadNum & MASK];
        ++curReadNum;
        return result;
    }

    // writer thread
    T* Obtain() {
        return &storage[curWriteNum & MASK];
    }

    // writer thread
    void Commit()
    {
                    // Ensure storage is written before mask is incremented ?
                    // insert memory barrier ?
        ++curWriteNum;
        if (curWriteNum - curReadNum > length)
        {
            std::cout <<
                "ArrayPool curWriteNum - curReadNum > length! " <<
                curWriteNum << " - " << curReadNum << " > " << length << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // writer thread
    void ObtainAndCommit(T* val) {
        memcpy(&storage[curWriteNum & MASK], val, sizeof(T));
        // copy constructor will likely be slower cause every field is copied
        // storage[curWriteNum & MASK] = *val;
        Commit();
    }

private:
    static const uint32_t length = 65536;
    static const uint32_t MASK = length - 1;
    T storage[length];

    // curWriteNum must be volatile because access from both
    // reader and writer threads
    // curReadNum don't need to be volatile because accessed
    // only from one (reader) thread
    volatile uint32_t curWriteNum;
    uint32_t curReadNum;
};

struct myStruct {
    int value;
};

ArrayPool<myStruct> pool;

void ReadThread() {
    myStruct* entry;
    while(true) {
        while ((entry = pool.TryGet()) != NULL) {
            std::cout << entry->value << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void WriteThread(int id) {
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(1000 * id);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);

    myStruct* storage = pool.Obtain();
    storage->value = id;
    pool.Commit();
    std::cout << "Commited value! " << id << std::endl;
}


int main( void )
{
    boost::thread readThread = boost::thread(&ReadThread);
    boost::thread writeThread;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        writeThread = boost::thread(&WriteThread, i);
    }
    writeThread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because of currWriteNum/curReadNum overflow you have a dependency on the ring size being a power of 2. You should write length in those terms or add a comment about the dependency.

Comment: Should an answer assume that you don't want to detect buffer overruns, because they're "impossible" or "undefined" or "not supported", for example because of scheduling or data-flow constraints in the threads which use this class?

Comment: @ChrisW of course. question is not about "rare" conditions. When someone will be wrong I can dig and fix. Question about "general scenario". Let's make this code working under "normal, assumed" conditions.

Comment: I'd #include <cstdint> instead of stdint.h. Second, I'm not 100% sure about that one, but your c'tor and d'tor of ArrayPool are empty, and you don't define copy/move c'tors, so I think it's better practice to omit the c'tor/d'tor and just let the compiler generate the code.

Comment: I am appalled by the number of people telling you to "just use locks." Yes, using a wait-free ringbuffer is overkill if your locks aren't contended or you don't need near-realtime performance. But if you're ever writing code that can't block--signal handlers and audio callbacks come to mind--then you need something like a ringbuffer. Telling you not to write one doesn't help at all with your understanding of *how* to write one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Boost Single-Producer Single-Consumer Queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html) should meet your needs. If you're trying to use this for production code and you don't understand why your completely unsynchronized code is a bad idea, don't try to roll your own based on advice from well-meaning passersby.

Comment: spsc_queue doesn't allow to reuse elements. I believe my implementation is VERY simple so at least for education it would be interesting to make it CORRECT.

Comment: i will check `spsc_queue` but i'm afraid it's a little bit slow too. it's using `copy-constructor` which must be slower than just one call to `memcpy`. But probably i can live with this. Another problem is that it doesn't allow to "reconfigure" elements. I like my `Obtain` `Commit` semantic because it allows me to put element even if I don't have anything to put.

Comment: also probably I can learn http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp and copy "synchronization" code from `spsc_queue` to my `queue`

Comment: also I don't like how `next_index` is implemented. I think it must be faster to apply "&" than `while (unlikely(ret >= max_size)) ret -= max_size;`

Comment: but in terms of synchronization I like `spsc_queue`, thanks, probably will use it!

Comment: Almost certainly `next_index` as implemented is better. The `unlikely` macro is used to give a hint to the branch prediction circuits in the processor (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel). So you get one missed branch prediction every (in this case) 65k pushes/pops, and in return you're saving at least two instructions (and possibly a memory load for MASK) on every push/pop.

Comment: copy constructor turns into a call to memcpy if the class is a pod type on most optimizers unless there is a faster way (which is the case with small classes).

Answer (score 11):

- there is absolutely no thread safety constructs, this means that you'll see a lot of *interesting* race conditions and memory inconsistencies
- just assuming dequeues happen fast enough does not mean they will in production
- you return `T` by value in `Obtain()`, instead of by reference so you can't actually write into it
- `Obtain` is a bad name, it sounds like it gets the next value like `TryGet` does
- `memcpy` is a bad idea to use to store the values if there is ever a custom copy constructor and a destructor
- that said `Obtain`->`store`->`Commit` can be put into a single `Put(T*)` member function
- eventually `curReadNum` and `curWriteNum` will overflow, it's not a real problem here because your length is a power of 2 and they are unsigned

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I think Obtain() must return T* so i can memcpy to internal storage. Note I store only "simple" things, simple structures. I don't need a code that works for any kind of data. I need maximum performance on my data. The question is if my code is good "in general" or if "design and idea good in general". Or you can suggest another approach.

Comment: @javapowered you should at least fix points 1 and 2, which deals with memory consistency (a.k.a. flush the written value out to the shared memory instead of the cache) and should dequeuing ever be delayed for whatever reason you must be able to handle that cleanly

Comment: "flush the written value out to the shared memory instead of the cache" how can I do that? can you give an example which demonstrates such kind of problem?

Comment: `Obtain->store->Commit can be put into a single Put(T*)` how? note I do not want to allocate memory at runtime.

Comment: @javapowered the Put will then do exactly as your `Obtain` -> store -> `Commit` does now, and you just pass a pointer or reference into `Put`

Comment: I see, the problem is that sometimes I do not have a pointer to memcpy. I reconfigure values in different way. But `Put(T*)` can be added in addition.

Comment: @javapowered then allocate one on the stack and pass a pointer to that

Comment: i don't want to reallocate memory - it's much faster to reuse memory

Answer (score 9):

## Use assignment instead of memcpy

A better implementation of Obtain can return a non-const reference which you can assign to:

```
T& Obtain() {
    return storage[curWriteNum & MASK];
}
```

Used like this:

```
void Processor::EnqueueFutOrderbook(orders* param)
{
    orders& storageItem = futOrdersUpdates.Obtain();
    storageItem = *param;
    futOrdersUpdates.Commit();
}
```

That deals with the "use the copy constructor instead of memcpy" suggested by @ratchetfreak.

*If you use memcpy instead of assignment then your code is incorrect for all types of T which have a non-trivial (e.g. user-defined) copy constructor.*

> Copy-construct will be slower than memcpy, isn't it?

The reason for using assignment is if T has a non-trivial copy-constructor (more accurately, an 'assignment operator'): for example if T is a `std::auto_ptr<>` or if it contains a `std::string`: if T has a non-trivial user-defined assignment operator, memcpy avoids calling it: which, may be faster but is incorrect behaviour!

In your example though your `T` is `myStruct`, which has a default (or non-existent) assignment operator. In that case the assignment is done by the compiler as an intrinsic, which is likely to be at least as fast as the run-time-library's `memcpy` function.

Which of the following do you think is faster:

```
void test()
{
    T source, target;
    // test the speed of `memcpy`
    for (int i = 0; i; i < 100000)
        memcpy(&target,&source,sizeof(T));
    // test the speed of compiler-generated assignment with copy-constructor
    for (int i = 0; i; i < 100000)
        target = source;
}
```

## An implementation which locks each method could be safe

One ('atomic') `Store` function would be easier to use than separate `Obtain` and `Commit` methods:

```
void Store(const T& newValue) {
    storage[curWriteNum & MASK] = newValue;
    ++curWriteNum;
    if (curWriteNum - curReadNum > length)
    {
        std::cout <<
            "ArrayPool curWriteNum - curReadNum > length! " <<
            curWriteNum << " - " << curReadNum << " > " << length << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Instead of trying "lock-free" code, adding locks as follows would make it safe.

```
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

template<class T> class ArrayPool
{
public:
    bool IsEmpty() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck (mtx);
        return curReadNum == curWriteNum;
    }

    bool TryGet(T& output)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck (mtx);
        if (curReadNum == curWriteNum)
        {
            return false;
        }
        output = storage[curReadNum++ & MASK];
        return true;
    }

    void Store(const T& newValue) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck (mtx);
        if (((curWriteNum+1) & MASK) == (curReadNum & MASK))
        {
            std::cout <<
                "ArrayPool curWriteNum - curReadNum > length! " <<
                curWriteNum << " - " << curReadNum << " > " << length << std::endl;
            throw std::exception();
        }
        storage[curWriteNum++ & MASK] = newValue;
    }

private:
    static const uint32_t length = 1 << 4;
    static const uint32_t MASK = length - 1;
    T storage[length];
    uint32_t curWriteNum;
    uint32_t curReadNum;
    std::mutex mtx;
};
```

Modify your client functions to call it like this:

```
void ReadThread() {
    myStruct entry;
    while(true) {
        if (pool.TryGet(entry)) {
            std::cout << entry.value << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void WriteThread(int id) {
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(1000 * id);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);

    myStruct storage;
    storage.value = id;
    pool.Store(storage);
    std::cout << "Commited value! " << id << std::endl;
}
```

> My primary requirement is latency. That's why I don't want to use lock, only memory barrier if absolutely required. And you don't ansered main question - if reader is guaranteed to see latest value. Should I insert memory barrier somewhere or something?

When I write code my primary requirement is always 'correctness' first. Usually the cost of a lock is:

- Trivial (unnoticeable) compared to whatever other processing the program is doing (for example, in your program, writing to `std::out`).
- Worth it for thread-safety.

## Your buffer overrun detection is broken

*I marked the following with `<strike>` because it is not relevent if you are not trying to detect a buffer overrun.*

<strike>This statement won't work after you store 2^32 items:</strike>

```
if (curWriteNum - curReadNum > length) { ... }
```

Instead use something like this, **before** you write to storage and increment curWriteNum:

```
if (((curWriteNum+1) & MASK) == (curReadNum & MASK))
{
    std::cout <<
        "ArrayPool curWriteNum - curReadNum > length! " <<
        curWriteNum << " - " << curReadNum << " > " << length << std::endl;
    throw std::exception(); // or, return false;
}
```

The following is very unsafe, because you return a pointer to memory which (because you've incremented ++curReadNum) you now think it is already safe to overwrite:

```
T* TryGet()
{
    if (curReadNum == curWriteNum)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    T* result = &storage[curReadNum & MASK];
    ++curReadNum;
    return result;
}
```

Try something like this instead:

```
bool TryGet(T& output)
{
    if (curReadNum == curWriteNum)
    {
        return false;
    }
    output = storage[curReadNum++ & MASK];
    return true;
}
```

> I not always have object which I can copy so I have to use Obtain.

In that case you can modify TryGet to return a pointer<strike>, however in that case you should delay incrementing curReadNum until after you have finished using the pointer:</strike>

```
    T* TryPeek()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck (mtx);
        if (curReadNum == curWriteNum)
        {
            return NULL; // or 'return 0;'
        }
        return &storage[curReadNum & MASK];
    }

    // Call this after TryPeek() to discard most recently peeked
    void Pop()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck (mtx);
        ++curReadNum;
    }
```

Which you can call like this:

```
void ReadThread() {
    myStruct* entry;
    while(true) {
        if (entry = pool.TryPeek()) {
            // Use the entry
            std::cout << entry->value << std::endl;
            // Discard the entry after finished using it
            pool.Pop();
        }
    }
}
```

> Thanks, I think no need to declare CurReadNum as volatile - buffer is never "overflow" so CurReadNum is actually read from one thread only.

That's true if (only if) you don't care about detecting buffer overruns.

> So declaring CurReadNum as volatile is absolutely useless ...

If you have code to detect buffer overruns (and you did write some such code in your OP) then it's not "absolutely useless": it may be `required`, to make that code work correctly. A problem with multi-threaded code is that testing cannot prove that it's correct: testing can only prove that it's incorrect. Correctness needs to built-in, by design and code inspection.

> ... but will likely add some latency.

I doubt whether you can devise a performance test which, in practice, can detect any difference in latency.

## Attempting a lock-free implementation

> And main question still not answered - if declaring curWriteNum as volatile is enough on modern Intel Xeon processor? I'm using 2 phisical processors server BTW. Is volatile enough and mandatory? Or memory barrier must/can be better?

If it were my code and I wanted it to be thread-safe, then I would use some kind of lock.

> I surely don't want to use lock as they are extremmely slow.

I think it's sufficient to put a memory fence at the start and end of every method, to emulate the memory fences which are implied by the lock_guard statements.

> of course I can "guard" every method, but I want to find certain places where memory barrier is REQUIRED but not more? I do not want to use more barriers than required.

I think the worry is that a compiler and CPU are allowed to reorder statements, and could theoretically write an incremented value to `curWriteNum` before writing to `storage`.

If you remove the unwanted overrun-detection code from my `Store` method then, as you say, the only memory that's used by both threads are `curWriteNum` and `storage`; so:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

template<class T> class ArrayPool
{
public:
    bool IsEmpty() {
        // 'data dependency' memory barrier here
        // or not because we don't mind if this return 'false positive' because we'll check again later
        return curReadNum == curWriteNum;
    }

    bool TryGet(T& output)
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            return false;
        }
        output = storage[curReadNum++ & MASK];
        return true;
    }

    T* TryPeek() // Unlike TryGet this leaves the element in Storage
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return &storage[curReadNum];
    }

    void Pop() // Call this after a successful TryPeek
    {
        ++curReadNum;
    }

    void Store(const T& newValue) {
         storage[curWriteNum & MASK] = newValue;
         // Ensure storage is written before mask is incremented
         _MemoryBarrier();
         ++curWriteNum;
    }

private:
    static const uint32_t length = 1 << 4;
    static const uint32_t MASK = length - 1;
    T storage[length];
    volatile uint32_t curWriteNum;
    uint32_t curReadNum;
};
```

The reason why I also declared curWriteNum as volatile is that, for some compilers, volatile is is a hint that the variable should not be enregistered.

For example, without volatile, a test like `while (curReadNum == curWriteNum)` might be translated to:

```
mov eax,[curReadNum] ; move memory value to a CPU register
mov ebx,[curWriteNum] ; move other memory value to a different CPU register
label_loop_top:
cmp eax,ebc ; compare the two values-in-registers
je label_loop_top ; loop while the in-register values are equal
```

This code (caused by not declaring that curWriteNum is volatile) will never detect a subsequent write to curWriteNum.

With volatile, the same compiler might translate `while (curReadNum == curWriteNum)` to:

```
mov eax,[curReadNum] ; move memory value to a CPU register
label_loop_top:
cmp eax,[curWriteNum] ; compare with the in-memory value
je label_loop_top ; loop while it matches the in-memory value
```

This code (caused by declaring that curWriteNum is volatile) should eventually detect a subsequent write to curWriteNum.

If you don't trust that `volatile` is sufficient to do this job, then theoretically you should have a memory barrier in the IsEmpty function above (to ensure that it will read `curWriteNum` from memory and not from a register), as well as having one in Store (to ensure that `storage` is written before `curWriteNum`).

If you don't have this second memory barrier then *theoretically* a compiler or machine (perhaps a smarter one than the one you're using now) will read `curWriteNum` from memory on its first loop through IsEmpty(), notice that your ReadThread() code never modifies `curWriteNum`, and therefore assume it can thereafter reuse its old, cached, enregistered value of `curWriteNum` instead of reading it from memory again.

Comment: i not always have object which I can copy so I have to use `Obtain`. I can add method `Put(T*)` in addition. Copy-construct will be slower than memcpy, isn't it? My primary requirement is latency. That's why I don't want to use `lock`, only memory barrier if absolutely required. And you don't ansered main question - if reader is guaranteed to see latest value. Should I insert memory barrier somewhere or something?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I think no need to declare CurReadNum as volatile - buffer is never "overflow" so CurReadNum  is actually read from one thread only. So declaring `CurReadNum` as `volatile` is absolutely useless but will likely add some latency. I guess nothing can be faster than `memcpy` so I prefer to keep using it even loosing readability. And main question still not answered - if declaring `curWriteNum` as `volatile` is enough on modern Intel Xeon processor? I'm using 2 phisical processors server BTW. Is `volatile` enough and mandatory? Or memory barrier must/can be better?

Comment: @javapowered And edited again.

Comment: thanks. `compiler-generated assignment is probably faster than memcpy` - how is that possible?. I surely don't want to use `lock` as they are extremmely slow. Let's wait probably someone can suggest how to modify code to be lock-free and valid. I need as much synchronization as required, but not more. `lock` would be overkill.

Comment: @javapowered For example, your myStruct contains one integer. So to assign one myStruct to another, the compiler only needs to assign one integer to another: using memcpy for that purpose is overkill. Also the compiler already knows `sizeof(T)` so it may be a waste of time for your code to load `sizeof(T)` as a memcpy parameter. IMO, at best the compiler might recognize memcpy as an 'intrinsic' function, and inline it, so that memcpy becomes as fast as the compiler assignment.

Comment: thanks, agree about using default copy-constructor! Now the only question I have is - where and what syncrhonization must be added for the best latency.

Comment: or! not sure "The default copy constructor for a C++ type works by invoking the copy constructor on each field in the instance with the corresponding field in the object the copy is being created from". So I'm afraid it might be slower than just once memcpy call!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12469/discussion-between-chrisw-and-javapowered)

Comment: `volatile` is not useful for thread safety (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484980/why-is-volatile-not-considered-useful-in-multithreaded-c-or-c-programming). `volatile` is to be used for memory-mapped hardware I/O, not to improve thread safety.

Comment: @ruds That depends on the compiler and version.

Comment: @ChrisW OK, let me put it another way. In standard C++, "operations on volatile variables are not atomic, nor do they establish a proper happens-before relationship for threading" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable). This is also true of standard C, and apparently of POSIX and Win32.

Comment: @ruds In some compilers, volatile is (or at least was) necessary to prevent the variable from being enregistered. I.e. 'while (foo==0)` might be translated to `mov eax,[foo];label: cmp eax,0; je label;` without the volatile switch (which never detects a subsequent write to foo), and `label: cmp [foo],0; je label;` with the volatile switch; without volatile the compiler might not expect another thread to change the memory at all. I'm not saying that volatile is sufficient: only that it may be necessary or desirable (with some compilers).

Comment: @javapowered How do you know that locking is too slow? Is this data structure a bottleneck in your program or are you just guessing? Locking and unlocking a mutex only takes about as long as a (uncached) main memory reference (aka ~100ns).

Comment: @ruds of course locking is too slow. yes this is intensively used structure and I have only several microseconds to do everything in my HFT application

Comment: @javapowered Did you profile your code? Did you try a structure using locks and find that it was not fast enough? Don't roll your own lock-free queue and expect to get it right; this is very complicated code.

Comment: @ruds when you write low latency code you don't need to profile to know that `lock` are expensive. I have NO `lock` in my entire application except several "non-critical" cases. Why do you suggest to use `lock` in place where they NOT mandatory? Definitely this can be implemented easily without lock.

Comment: +200 for the effort, but it seems i really can just use boost spsc_queue

Answer (score 6):

just as an example of possible race conditions consider the function:

```
void WriteThread(int id) {
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(1000 * id);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);

    myStruct* storage = pool.Obtain();
    storage->value = id;
    pool.Commit();
    std::cout << "Commited value! " << id << std::endl;
}
```

then inline all called functions (which the compiler is allowed to do) (note this is pseudo code roughly representing what could happen).

```
void WriteThread(int id) {
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(1000 * id);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);

    myStruct* storage = pool.storage[pool.curWriteNum & MASK];
    storage->value = id;
    ++pool.curWriteNum; //ignoring the if and output because it is not relevant for this evample
    std::cout << "Commited value! " << id << std::endl;
}
```

now remember that volatile is not a fence but only stops the compiler from reordering with regard to other volatiles. The compiler is also allowed to store variables in temperaries whenever needed (as long as the "as if" rule stands for a single threadded program). So this reordering is leagal:

```
void WriteThread(int id) {
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(1000 * id);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);

    auto temp = pool.curWriteNum & MASK;
    ++pool.curWriteNum; 
    //starting here the other thread can start reading causing a race condition
    myStruct* storage = pool.storage[temp];
    storage->value = id;
    std::cout << "Commited value! " << id << std::endl;
}
```

It should also be noted that volatile does not stop load and store reordering on hardware that supports this so even if the optimizer doesn't shoot you in the foot the hardware still may. It is also important to understand that what reordering happens where is very hard to predict so it is best to expect the worst. It may not be reordered the first time you look at the assembler but then you change something somewhere months later, maybe even in a completely different header which does not even use and you can't imagine the optimizer will change its behavior but it does and its allowed to and your code breaks, not on your machine but on your most important customers. Honestly you can't tell me with a straight face that you want to inspect every single spot these functions get inlined with -O3 optimization in assembler every time you recompile your project.

I would suggest using c++11 std::atomic variables for curWriteNum and curReadNum. This would at least solve the stated race condition.

It is also not a good idea to not handle an overflow. No matter how fast the consumer thread is it is next to impossible to prove that it will never have to wait for a lock for too long. As soon as it allocates memory (through new or otherwise) or even uses a function which could throw an exception derived from std::exception (which almost all exceptions are) then there is chance chance it will wait for the heap lock which literally take minutes in a worst case scenario where RAM has been swapped to an old, slow HD. Bottom line is that it probably will never happen on your machine but it probably will to some of your customers and they will then likely not remain your customers after that.

Comment: +1 That's an example why it's better (i.e. "more correct" even if not "proven necessary via testing") to have a fence after writing to `storage` and before incrementing `curWriteNum`.

Comment: If this may happen then it would be very interesting to reproduce it. I believe you, but if this issue is so hard to reproduce probably it just will never happen? Also it would be nice to see "proposed fix". Should I have memory barrier AND volatile variable or it's enough to have just volatile variable?

Comment: also MSDN states that C# "MemoryBarrier is required only on multiprocessor systems with weak memory ordering (for example, a system employing multiple Intel Itanium processors).". So if C# MemoryBarrier and C++ MemoryBarrier are similar, then C++ MemoryBarrier is useless on Intel Xeon?

Comment: @javapowered to be honest my memory barrier experience with production code comes from embedded ARM hardware so I'm not so sure about Intel. I would strongly suggest never ever using code in production which theoretically has a bug but is hard to reproduce in practice, it will bite you.

Comment: The one time you could 'prove' there will be no overrun is when the system/protocol is throttled somehow, e.g. if the producer never creates more than 'n' unprocessed/outstanding requests.

Comment: yes but if you have that then why not just build it into the quque ?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, if you don't have a strong grasp of the content in [intro.multithread] of the C++ standard, it's a bad idea to write or maintain lock-free code. In nearly all cases, the costs due to more difficult maintenance, data corruption, etc of lock-free code will exceed the small additional CPU cost of just using locks.

---

Thus, my preferred implementation is this:

```
template <typename T> class ArrayPool {
  public:
    ArrayPool() = default;
    bool IsEmpty() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);
        return IsEmptyLocked();
    }
    T* TryGet() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);
        if (IsEmptyLocked()) return nullptr;
        return GetLocked();
    }
    // Waits until this ArrayPool contains entries, then
    // returns an entry.
    T* WaitAndGet() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);
        nonempty.wait(lock, std::bind(&ArrayPool::IsNonEmpty, this));
        return GetLocked();
    }
    T* Obtain() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);
        return ObtainLocked();
    }
    void Commit() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);
        ++curWriteNum;
    }
    void ObtainAndCommit(T&& t) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);
        *ObtainLocked() = std::move(t);
        ++curWriteNum;
    }
    void ObtainAndCommit(const T& t) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);
        // Using the copy constructor is always correct, and for PODs
        // should be just as fast as memcpy.
        *ObtainLocked() = t;
        ++curWriteNum;
    }

  private:
    // Precondition: mu is held
    bool IsEmptyLocked() const {
        return (curWriteNum & MASK) == (curReadNum & MASK);
    }
    // Preconditions: mu is held, !IsEmptyLocked()
    T* GetLocked() {
        return &storage[curReadNum++ & MASK];
    }
    // Precondition: mu is held
    T* ObtainLocked() {
        // optional but recommended error checking
        if (((curWriteNum + 1) & MASK) == (curReadNum & MASK)) {
            // The producer has outrun the consumer
            throw std::runtime_error("Queue full");
        }
        return &storage[curWriteNum & MASK];
    }

    static const std::size_t length = 1ul << 16;
    static const std::size_t MASK = length - 1;

    T storage[length];

    mutable std::mutex mu;
    // All members declared below are mu-guarded.
    std::condition_variable nonempty;
    std::size_t curReadNum;
    std::size_t curWriteNum;
};
```

Note `WaitAndGet`; you should modify `ReadThread` to call that and avoid busy-waiting:

```
void ReadThread() {
    while (true) {
        auto* entry = pool.WaitAndGet();
        std::cout << entry->value() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

It appears that you'll be unable to do better than locking in this situation. You need to be sure of two things:

1. Modifications to `curReadNum` and `curWriteNum` are immediately visible to the reader and writer thread (both threads observe both variables).
2. Modifications to `storage[i]` made by the writer thread are visible to the reader thread before reading.

Because writes to `curWriteNum` don't depend on `storage[i]`, this requires release-acquire semantics (for example, see the discussion of happens-before at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order). That is essentially what `mutex`'s lock/unlock give you.

Comment: `locking` is very expensive. so far it seems this code works withoug locking (i'm using it). is it so diffucult to make it lock-free? I have just one thread that write (and never read) and one thread that read (and never write). This is simple thing!

Comment: You're spending money with the output of this thing and you're cool with opening yourself up to memory corruption due to data races? If you're only using one reader and one writer, why not just use one thread for the whole process?